# importing a file with asterisk in its name (Linux machines)

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I am trying to import a file:

```
filename = "furan.b3lyp.6-31G*.sdat"
path = "/home/molkee/Desktop/plots/scr/" <> filename;
FileExistsQ[path]
data = Import[path, "Table"];
```

I am getting the *Recursion Limit* error. I guess this happens because of the asterisk in the filename, but why?

What is going on? What is the right way to import it?

[FILE](http://www71.zippyshare.com/v/76901079/file.html)

Comment: MMA is interpreting * to mean a wildcard (placeholder for 0 or more characters). I'm not on a Linux machine (Windows doesn't allow * in filenames) so I can't test this, but "furan.b3lyp.6-31G" <> Verbatim["*"] <> ".sdat" might work. Or `Verbatim` around the whole thing.

Comment: Is possible to "escape" the star in a filename using a special character? \ or something?

Comment: Oh right I didn't think about that. Probably: try `\\*`

Comment: nope, this does not work

Comment: Did you also try `\*`?

Comment: yes, I did. didn't help

Comment: @molkee Works like a charm for me, see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/smg66.png).

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the file itself, then.

Comment: @Öskå what is the trick here? seems like I did the same

Comment: @mfvonh the file is OK. everything works once I remove the star

Comment: I believe that @mfvonh is right indeed :) Can you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: @Öskå added the file

Comment: @molkee I don't have any issue either: picture [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nwW0x.png). Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: @Öskå What MMA version? I moved to my Linux machine (9) and I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mfvonh I'm on _version 8_ :)

Comment: It appears this is a problem with whatever `Import` is doing to determine how to import the file. Seems like a bug to me since escaping doesn't work. All I can suggest is rename the file or work around the problem with `OpenRead` (worked fine) or something.

Comment: thanks guys! just wanted to understand what was going on. there must be a workaround though

Comment: BTW, the same thing happens with ANY file containing an asterisk in the filename, this is a version-related issue

Comment: Worth reporting as a bug to Wolfram.

Comment: I can confirm this, redhat linux, mma 9.0.1 With my own very simple file.  `Open` fails as well so it is not to do with `Import`.    The workaround is to not use * in linux file names ( seriously this is bad for other reasons )

Comment: @george2079 i know it is not a good idea to use '*' in filenames, but sometimes I have to and, in my opinion, such files should be imported correctly regardless of the star (at least, there should be a way of how to "escape" tricky characters)

Comment: @george2079 please consider posting an answer.